# Add ListView to Tab in Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing an application that need 2 tabs: "Normal" and "Hard"
I created that two tabs. Everything is OK

Now I want to add a listview into Normal Tab, but the application crashes right after I launch it

Here is my project

-Class

+MainActivity.java

```
  public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // Tab for Nomal
    TabSpec nomallv = tabHost.newTabSpec("Normal");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    nomallv.setIndicator("Normal");
    Intent nIntent = new Intent(this, NormalListActivity.class);
    nomallv.setContent(nIntent);

    // Tab for Hard
    TabSpec hardlv = tabHost.newTabSpec("Hard");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    hardlv.setIndicator("Hard");
    Intent hIntent = new Intent(this, HardListActivity.class);
    hardlv.setContent(hIntent);



    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(nomallv); // Adding tab
    tabHost.addTab(hardlv); // Adding tab
  }
}
```

+NormalListActivity

```
public class NormalListActivity extends ListActivity {

String[] normallist = {"Home Town", "A trip to the country", "Story of Little Pea", "As long as you love me"
        , "The way to success", "Pursuit of Happiness"};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.normallevellayout);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.normallevellayout, normallist);

    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewN);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }

}
```

+HardListActiviity

```
 public class HardListActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hardlevellayout);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

}
```

-And here the layouts:

+activity_main:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

+hardlevellayout

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f7d1d7"
android:orientation="vertical" >


 </LinearLayout>
```

+normalevellayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#b7e2ec"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewN"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is the listview in tab
Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using Fragments Pager Adapter to achieve this then load the corresponding fragments in each tab - then inside those fragments, load the ListView and whatever you need respectively.

Comment: whats the error log? please post

Comment: is there any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

Change id to inside normallevellayout:

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
```

And also inflate correct layout for list item. Something like :

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.text, normallist);

ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

text layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/txt"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Alternate solution : 
Keep text.xml and
Change in NormalListActivity as :

```
// setContentView(R.layout.normallevellayout);
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.text, normallist);

ListView listView = getListView();//(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: android:id="@android:id/list" has eror

Comment: not work my friend! Is there any ways that we dont need to change the id? thank you for your support

Comment: If you are extending ListActivity then you need to use, android.R.id.list